# Defining more than one path in VS Code PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

I cannot find a clear answer on how to define multiple paths for the PYTHONPATH variable. I have tried all possible combinations of different solutions posted on various sites, but none of them work. Why can't this be clearly documented somewhere?

I tried every combination of separator and quoting:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "D:\\Users\\path\\a\\"; "D:\\Users\\path\\b\\"},
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "D:\\Users\\path\\a\\": "D:\\Users\\path\\b\\"},
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "D:\\Users\\path\\a\\; D:\\Users\\path\\b\\"},
...
```

Comment: Are you using this `launch.json` configuration?

Comment: Yes, this is through launch.json. The error was caused by the space; compare the different between the 3rd line in the question and @shookees answer without the space after the semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode's `env` setting corresponds to operating system's environment variables.
Setting settings under the same name would either yield an error or pick one of the values. Here you should use only a single `env` setting, as well as, set `PYTHONPATH` once.

In order to use multiple directories, *one or more directory pathnames separated by os.pathsep (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows)*[1]. guessing that your operating system is Windows, the setting would looke like this:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "D:\\Users\\path\\a\\;D:\\Users\\path\\b\\"}
```

[1] - https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH